# Generalized Trigonometric Identities

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, analysis

We know that $\cos A\cos B+\sin A\sin B=\cos(A-B)$.

My question is what is the result of $\cos A\cos B+X\sin A\sin B$?

Answer (score 1):

It depend what you actually want. maybe this is the simples expression in some calculations. but if you're interested in reformulating this with trigonometric function of forms $A \pm B$ ; i think this is the way to do it: 
using
$$
\sin A \sin B = \frac{1}{2} (\cos(A-B)-\cos (A+B)) \\
\cos A \cos B = \frac{1}{2} (\cos(A-B)+\cos (A+B))
$$
the expression becomes
$$
\cos A \cos B + X \sin A \sin B = \frac{1}{2} (\cos(A-B)+\cos (A+B)) + \frac{X}{2} (\cos(A-B)-\cos (A+B)) \\
=\big( \frac{1+X}{2}\big) \cos(A-B) + \big( \frac{1-X}{2}\big) \cos(A+B).
$$
If $X=1$, you can see the result is $\cos(A-B)$ again.

Comment: thank you for your comment. it is helpful.